# paho js mqtt client fires onConnect event

Tags: javascript, client, mqtt, paho

I am connecting to mosquitto using paho js client. It connects ok. But the onConnect event is firing non stop. I was checking the logs in broker, and it looks that it just connects once. Why is this happening? I just used the code which apears on oficial web:

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript MQTT WebSocket Example</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho- mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript">
     </script>
     <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
           var host = "192.168.1.200";
        var port = 1884;
        // Create a client instance
         client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, port, "abcd");

     // set callback handlers
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

// connect the client
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});


// called when the client connects
function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  client.subscribe("World");
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  message.destinationName = "World";
  client.send(message);
    console.log("messageSent");
}

// called when the client loses its connection
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
}

// called when a message arrives
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}

      </script>
   </head>
     <body>
   <h1>Main Body</h1>
    <script>
    </script>
   </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: How many users do you have?

Comment: just one. I am testing the websocket connection on mosquitto

Comment: I sow on github, there were other people having the same issue with mosquito 1.5. But I didn't find any solution for it

Comment: A quick look at some of the issue implies this might be fixed at Mosquitto 1.5.1 If not downgrading to 1.4.15  is probably the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I generally notice this when my client ID, here "abcd", has already been connected. For deploying on multiple devices I made this a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by samwell the problem lies in the `clientID`.

If two clients uses the same clientID, the last "kicks out" the client connected earlier.
I think because Mosquitto maintains a single websocket per clientID.

Paho JS reports to the `onConnectionLost` callback one of these two errors:

- code 7: AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined
- code 8: AMQJS0008I Socket closed

Use a unique ID for the client or use a user specific one.